# Symfony2 - Setting user access restriction to a specific entity

Tags: symfony, user-permissions

I'm working a project where the main page is a portal, and each link is a client's blog page.

My question, is how would I setup access restriction for each client to their specific blog page?

e.g.
Main page portal

- Link1 -> blog1 page
- Link2 -> blog2 page
- Link3 -> blog3 page

I need to figure out a way to limit CRUD access per user to their specific blog only.

For example:

- User1 -> access restricted to Blog1 page
- User2 -> access restricted to Blog2 page
- User3 -> access restricted to Blog3 page

For setup: I started going with 1 category entity and linking to post entity, but now I'm thinking that there would be no way to limit access to just one category entity/post entity.

Any ideas on how to best handle this? (use different category entities and post entities or is there a bundle that takes care of what I'm trying to do?)

Comment: Why don't you simply use [roles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles) (e.g. `ROLE_USER_BLOG1`)?

Comment: Can you put this in a form of an answer and a basic example and I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try and leverage the existing SF2 access control feature: [Roles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#roles)

A user that only is allowed to read Blog1 could have the role `ROLE_USER_BLOG1`.
Another one that is allowed to create articles might have `ROLE_ADMIN_BLOG1`.
And a third one that is allowed to read all blogs could have `ROLE_USER_BLOG_ALL`.

Together with a [custom voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html) an implementation for your system should be straightforward. ;-)

Comment: This approach seems like it could get unwieldy quite quickly as if you have 100 bloggers you would have 100 roles + any extra roles like your `ROLE_USER_BLOG_ALL` and how is each role going to be added?

Comment: @Qoop That is an entirely different question. Adding roles could be done by a simple interface (e.g. adding users to blogs or adding blogs to users). Concerning the unwieldy part, I must partly disagree. User management isn't simple most of the time. ;-)

Comment: I would have thought a far easier way of working for would be for each blog to have an owner field (or an actual association to a user) that could then be used to restrict capabilities. The above that there could be a hierarchy (blog_all, admin, super_admin) that would then have higher capabilities and access. With a single role for a single user then you would have to keep track of all available roles to make sure no conflicts came about. I may be wrong though.